# Remove an object with a certain property from an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, java-collections-api

I have a customer object with three properties: last name, first name, and SIN number

If the user enters the customer's last name and first name, and the object is found in the arraylist, the objects gets removed.

```
private static void deleteCustomer (String lastName, String firstName, List<Customer> accounts)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++)
    {            
        accounts.get(i);
        public int compare (Customer c1, Customer c2) 
        {
            Customer customerOne = (Customer) c1;
            Customer customerTwo = (Customer) c2;
            if (lastName.equals(CustomerOne.getLastName()) && firstName.equals(CustomerOne.getFirstName()))
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If two customers have the same first and last name, the user is asked to enter the SIN number, that's why I have the compare method. I'm not sure what to do after this.

Updated method:

```
public static void deleteCustomer (String lastName, String firstName, List<Customer> accounts)
{
    for (Iterator<Customer> iterator = accounts.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
    {
        Customer customer = iterator.next();
        if(lastName.equals(customer.getLastName()) && firstName.equals(customer.getFirstName()))
        {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but it removes all customers with the same first and last name

Comment: Before you think about what to write inside the `compare` method, think about where to place it. Hint: inside another method is not a good place.

Comment: Does this compile? Your compare method is inside the deleteCustomer method?

Comment: Yes, it compiles. I have updated the original post with the new method

Comment: `Yes, it compiles.` No, it doesn't. The updated code maybe does, but not the first one.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply wish to delete **one** customer as you have described in the question you should *break the loop* after you have found the correct customer and removed it:

```
iterator.remove();
break; // breaks the loop
```

But, since it seems as if there may be multiple customers with the same first+lastname the algorithm is not exactly bullet-proof. Maybe a customer id or similar should be used to distinguish between customers. In the case of a customer id the data structure to use should quite possibly be a `Map<CustomerId, Customer>`. Customers can then be quickly accessed via the id and you still can retrieve a collection of all customers by invoking the `values()` method.

In addition to this, if you don't want to modify the original `List` you can also use a Java 8 construct where you `stream`, `filter` and `collect` your data.

```
final List<Customer> newAccountList = accounts.stream()
            .filter(c -> !(Objects.equals(c.getFirstName(), firstName) &&
                    Objects.equals(c.getLastName(), lastName)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `List` above contains everything from the original `List` except for those entries where first+lastname matches.

Comment: Every customer has a unique SIN number. Would I still have to implement Map<> to distinguish between them?

Comment: @user3479783 Either you use a `Map<String, Customer>` where the key is the `SIN` (a good aproach). Or, you can remove customers based on the `SIN` instead of first+lastname.